# Jest js node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\cli\index.js:227 } catch {

Tags: javascript, npm, jestjs

I run `npm init` `npm i -D jest` like in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7r4xVDI2vho&t=621s)

I am getting this error after running commend `nmp test`

This is not an error from creatures.js or creatures.test.js because without this file error happening. How can I fix this ? I tried already reinstating mode_modules. I don't know it have a matter but I'm using node 8.17.0 because I'm working with Firebase cloud functions

```
PS C:\Users\Pawel\Desktop\HerosIIIJS> npm test

> heros_iii_js@1.0.0 test C:\Users\Pawel\Desktop\HerosIIIJS
> jest

C:\Users\Pawel\Desktop\HerosIIIJS\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\build\cli\index.js:227
    } catch {
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:617:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:597:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pawel\Desktop\HerosIIIJS\node_modules\jest\node_modules\jest-cli\bin\jest.js:16:3)
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

```
const getProjectListFromCLIArgs = (argv, project) => {
  const projects = argv.projects ? argv.projects : [];

  if (project) {
    projects.push(project);
  }

  if (!projects.length && process.platform === 'win32') {
    try {
      projects.push((0, _jestUtil().tryRealpath)(process.cwd()));
    } catch { // <= error
      // do nothing, just catch error
      // process.binding('fs').realpath can throw, e.g. on mapped drives
    }
  }

  if (!projects.length) {
    projects.push(process.cwd());
  }

  return projects;
};
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "heros_iii_js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.2"
  }
}
```

file structure:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Node 8 doesn't support the optional catch binding syntax, [Jest 26](https://jestjs.io/blog/2020/05/05/jest-26#other-breaking-changes-in-jest-26) no longer supports it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix unexpected token in ESLint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62636329/how-to-fix-unexpected-token-in-eslint)

Comment: Did I need to install the newest node (I don't want to do this because Firebase cloud functions work on node 8 in spark plan) or can I chose a different jest version , how can i do this ?

Comment: I don't use ESLint

Comment: No, you don't use ESLint but the answer there explains what the error is and why, and you have the same options: upgrade Node; or downgrade the library to a version that supports Node 8. It also shows the command to run for the second option, you just need to replace the name and the version (version that dropped support - 1).

Comment: ok i find it i upadate my version to newwest with this https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows/releases

Comment: Well then won't you have the problem that your code might not work when you deploy it? You're testing it for a version of Node that's not what it will run on in production, that seems unwise.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Upgrade node.js
In old version of node they were not handled the catch block of jest file.

It will work from node -v9.11.2 to so on.

Comment: to the point nice!